# plotting a time series graph in px.line plotly express

Tags: express, date, plotly, schedule

I can't build a schedule in plotly express.` It turns out a graph with a lot of lines

```
fig = px.line(new_df, x='Data', y='quantity')
fig.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHJA6.png)

```
new_df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 59 entries, 13 to 9686
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column                     Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------                     --------------  -----         
 0   Data                       59 non-null     datetime64[ns]
 1   quantity                   59 non-null     int64         
 2   Year                       59 non-null     int64         
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), int64(2)
memory usage: 1.8 KB
```

The graph is plotted using seaborn correctly

```
sns.lineplot(x='Data', y='quantity', hue='Year', data=new_df)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezKLT.png)

my details [enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1poXsRP8wBQbTJZp0cwRwJ2bbXOogpqNF/view?usp=sharing)

my notebook [enter link description here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1OLwptWxiFvDIAiIbC8KZDhBdbRHT9iIf?usp=sharing)

Comment: The graph was created with similar test data. I can't be sure since the actual data is not presented, but it appears to be interpreted as a string. Try specifying that the x-axis is a time series intentionally. `fig.update_xaxes(type='date')`

Comment: @r-beginners,
i added the csv file and my notebook. Graphs don't work on plotly, everything is fine on seaborn

Comment: I was able to build on the altair interactive library.

Comment: I was able to confirm the causes using the data you posted: first, the current date format could not be automatically converted by plotly; second, the time series data was not in ascending chronological order. `new_df['Data']=pd.to_datetime(new_df['Data'], format='%d.%m.%Y');
new_df.sort_values('Data', ascending=True, inplace=True)`

Comment: Thank you very much. I just started studying. Your solution is perfect!!! Everything worked out!! I suffered for two days before writing here

Comment: I wanted to mark your answer as correct, but I don't have a gray tick to change it to green, as written in the instructions for the site

Comment: If you respond instead of commenting, there will be a check mark. I did not respond to this question because it is a common case. Good luck.